# Des choses qu'on aime vs Des choses que l'on aime

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, abréviations

It seems the two phrases

```
Des choses qu'on aime 
Des choses que l'on aime
```

have the same meaning. Nevertheless I notice the second phrase more often than the first.

What is the grammatical rule behind the second phrase ? What is the full form of  `l'` here ? For example let's say if it stands for `le/la`, can I say otherwise `Des choses que la nous aimons/le vous aimez` (which I have never seen), or only the construct `que l'on aime` exists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sentences have exactly the same meaning, but "que l'on" will be recommended for euphony. The form "l'on" is actually a remnant from the original form "l'hom", which used to mean "l'Homme": it was "l'on" in all positions, but the "l'" has disappeared, except in some positions. Both forms are valid nowadays. The form "l'on" may be more common in written text.

Taken from [this article](http://grammaire.reverso.net/3_1_44_on_lon.shtml):

> On trouve parfois le pronom on précédé de l'article élidé l'.
>
> Pour éviter deux voyelles orales
>
> L'article l' sert à éviter le rapprochement à l'oral de deux voyelles,
> plus particulièrement quand on suit et, ou, où, pourquoi, qui, quoi,
> si. Si l'on tient compte de tous les avis, il est possible de
> satisfaire tout le monde. C'est un endroit où l'on se sent très bien.
>
> Pour éviter le son "con"
>
> L'article se place devant on si ce dernier suit que et ses composés
> lorsque, puisque, quoique pour éviter le son "con". Quoi que l'on en
> dise, les résultats ne sont pas si mauvais (mieux que quoi qu'on en
> dise). Il est difficile de s'arrêter lorsque l'on a commencé jeune
> (mieux que lorsqu'on a commencé). L'article est plus fréquent encore
> si le mot qui suit on commence lui-même par le son "con". Puisque l'on
> compare deux situations différentes… (mieux que puisqu'on compare).

As it is a remnant of an article used with "on" and not a pronoun, you cannot transpose it with "nous" as in your example "*des choses que la nous aimons*"

More references:

- [On the etymology](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/culture-generale/etymologie-forme-sens-accord-du-pronom-on/)
- [On the origin and usage](https://www.druide.com/fr/enquetes/et-lon)